# c program that calculates the number of different words

Tags: c

i am trying to make a program that the user will constantly give separate words and the programm will calculate all different words.
For example: User gives: "Hello", User gives: "Bye", User gives: "Good", User gives: "Bad", User gives: "Bye".
These are 4 different words.
I want it to calculate them when the user has finished giving words.
This is some code i wrote, but i cant finish it. I am new in programmaming and this question might seem silly but it is pretty important for me.

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num=0,b=0,h=0,g=0;
    char name[31],text[2000];
    while (num==0){
        printf("give word: \n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("%s\n", name);
        if (strcmp(name,"*fff*")==0){
            num=1;
        }
        else {
            h=h+1;
            b=b+strlen(name);
            strcpy(text,name);


        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: It sounds like you want **unique** words

Comment: You are missing a lot of logic to accomplish what you want.  You need some way to store all the previous entries, so as each new entry is added, you can compare against all the previous entries.  That being said, writing out the entire logic tree is a bit too broad for this format.

Comment: i want the number of different words. the words that appear more than one time count for 1. i am new and dont know these stuff very well. i know i am missing logic. :/   i need every new word to be compared with the old ones.. but i dont know how to do that

Comment: you need a loop to compare `name` to each item in the `text` array.  Right now, your only comparison is with `"*fff*"` which terminates the program.

Comment: yes i know. i tried some ways but everything was wrong.

Comment: well you should at least show one attempt that has a loop in it, if you don't understand why the loop didn't work.  Right now, without a loop or a second `strcmp`, it is impossible to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the words in one giant character array, you should create an array of character arrays and then check the entire array each time for duplicates. It would be relatively inefficient but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you read a word, convert it to a unique 32-bit hash.  It is much faster and easier to search in a sorted array of integers than to do 1000's of string compares.